# Check unique name validation for storage account in CreateUiDefinition

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-rm-template

Looking for help with code on validation of the storage account name as unique in the CreateUiDefinition. Here is the code snippet from the template which I tried:

```json
{
    "name": "storageaccountname",
    "type": "Microsoft.Common.TextBox",
    "label": "Storage Account Name",
    "toolTip": "",
    "constraints": {
                    "validations": [
                     {
                       "isValid": "[not(in(resourceGroup(), 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts'))]", 
                       "message": "Name already taken"
                      }]
                   }
}
```

[image: Storage Account creation]

As you can see, even after providing the unique name it's still showing

> Name already taken.

Comment: the storage account name should be in small letters and length should be of 3 to 24 characters. Have you tried that ?

Comment: @MadhurajVadde-MT the main issue is I wanted to put a storage name validation checker in the text box so, there are few conditions on that. 

* Name should be unique (Main problem)
* Name should be in lower letters and length should be 3 to 24 characters.

Answer (score 0):

It says,

*"The name must be unique across all existing storage account names in Azure. It must be 3 to 24 characters long, and can contain only lowercase letters and numbers."*

So you can have any combination of **lowercase letters and numbers**